# How to sort JSON by field

Tags: php, json, api

I need to sort an array alphabetically directly when getting the result of an API in PHP.
I need to sort by GROUP ALIAS and DEVICE ALIAS going inside GROUPS.
This is what I currently have:

```
 <?php

// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

 
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://webapi.teamviewer.com/api/v1/devices');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$computadoras = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
$computadoras= json_decode($computadoras);




$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://webapi.teamviewer.com/api/v1/groups?sort=alias');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$grupos = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);


$grupos= json_decode($grupos);

  


foreach($grupos->groups as $group)
{
    

    if($group->name!='')
    {
    echo "<p class='bg-white p-2 rounded-sm text-warning font-weight-bold'> <a class='text-warning' data-toggle='collapse' href='#".$group->id."' role='button' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='collapseExample'>".$group->name." </a> </p>";
    
    echo "<div class='collapse' id='".$group->id."'>
    <div class='card card-body'>";

    foreach($computadoras->devices as $device)
    {
        if($device->groupid == $group->id)
        {
            if($device->alias!='')
            {
            if($device->online_state=="Online")
            {
               echo "<p>".$device->alias." <a href='tvcontrol1://control?device=".$device->teamviewer_id."' class=' btn btn-warning ' style='float:right;' > <i class='ni ni-laptop'></i></a>";
            }
            if($device->online_state=="Offline")
            {
               echo "<p>".$device->alias." <a href='tvcontrol1://control?device=".$device->teamviewer_id."' class=' btn btn-warning disabled ' style='float:right;' > <i class='ni ni-laptop'></i></a>";
            }
        }
        }
    }
    echo "</div></div>";
}
}
```

It is not feasible to order it in javascript by the size of the array since it freezes the web.
I searched on internet for several ways and they all use usort() but I can't adapt it to my source code

Comment: As far as I can see, you are trying to loop a json array in the outer loop and if it matches a value in an array in the inner loop, you echo something. -- That is all PHP. Why tagging it with JavaScript?

Comment: Because this information is sent via ajax to the front end. Which is javascript handled